# Diferencia entre \r y \n JAVA

Tags: java

se conocen como secuencias de escape. He estado probando algunas, y he visto que \r y \n generan nuevas líneas, aunque tienen definiciones distintas y según he leído, funciones también diferentes. ¿Alguien sabe la diferencia?

```
System.out.print("Diferencia entre usar \r");
System.out.print("O usar \n");
```

Si sirve, dejo este enlace, aunque no he entendido muy bien su explicación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260126/what-are-the-differences-between-char-literals-n-and-r-in-java

Comment: aqui tienes la explicacion detallada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Gracias @LeisnielCabreraPereira , pero recuerda que muchos de los miembros de la comunidad no conocemos o iniciamos apenas en aprender el idioma inglés, por eso es bueno agregar una traducción ya que este enlace tal vez no es útil para todos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En realidad no son lo mismo, las definiciones pueden darte una idea de como funcionan:

> `\n` : (Line Feed) mueve el cursor hacia la siguiente línea sin volver al comienzo
>   de la línea.
>
> `\r` : Retorno de carro (Carriage return), mueve el cursor al comienzo de la  línea sin avanzar a la siguiente linea.

Comúnmente se usan ambas `\r\n`. Esto para iniciar una nueva linea. Mueve el cursor al inicio de la linea (`\r`) y mueve el cursor hacia la siguiente linea (`\n`).

---

Una analogía de la cual es precisamente se obtuvieron las descripciones  sería la que se agrega en el [**blog Penguin Pete´s**](http://penguinpetes.com/b2evo/index.php?title=argh_microsoft_notepad_crlf_argh), donde muestra una antigua maquina de escribir ([**Typewriter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typewriter)).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Retorno de carro, mueve al inicio de la línea para escribir pero necesitamos cambiar de linea para no escribir sobre la misma, entonces movemos la palanca (line feed).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]